# 301 htaccess redirect doesnt work old link to new one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have old link that still works with new one because u can type what u want on

```
en/oldname/cat,2,1,1
```

in place "oldname" could be even santa

```
en/santa/cat,2,1,1
```

and will show page with id 2,1,1 so i need to move permanent 301 from oldname to newname and below code in htaccess doesnt work

```
RewriteRule ^en/oldname/cat,2,1,1(.*)$ /en/newname/cat,2,1,1$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Maybe is that because Rewrite rule should show page only takes id to change page?

I was trying few 301 redirects, even redirectmatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.domain.com/en/oldname/cat,2,1,1(.*) http://www.domain.com/en/newname/cat,2,1,1/$1

Redirect 301 http://www.domain.com/en/oldname/cat,2,1,1 http://www.domain.com/en/newname/cat,2,1,1
```

doesnt work too

Comment: I have just tested your RewriteRule without problems. Going to "http://localhost/en/oldname/cat,2,1,1,1234" redirects to "http://localhost/en/newname/cat,2,1,1,1234" as expected. 

Have you remembered to enable the rewrite engine (RewriteEngine on)?